# Type parameters in a method

Tags: java, generics

I would like to write a generic method which takes a Set including either Integer or String values. The method should partition that given Set and return a list which contains sets of the generic type. I am quite new to generics and have a problem with the code specified below. The compiler don't likes the T in the method signature. What is the problem?

```
private List<Set<T>> createChunkSet(Set<T> set) {
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Your code needs to know that `T` is generic type, not some raw type like String. Where did you declare `T`? Is it in class declaration like `class MyClass<T>{...}`?

Comment: @Pshemo, He does not need to. This is generic method, independent of generic class declaration.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I have changed my previous comment a little. I am aware of that this should probably be generic method but I am trying to make OP realise that if he wants `T` to be generic type he needs to declare it as generic somewhere in his code.

Comment: *... which gets a Set including either Integer or String values.* - means your method is not actually generic. A generic method should work for any type (considering no type boundary - which you don't seem to have in your case). Sounds like you need to different methods.

Comment: @Pshemo, Yes, that is correct. Either in the method as `<T>` or in the class declaration as you have mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method declaration :

```
private <T> List<Set<T>> createChunkSet(Set<T> set) {
   // your code here
}
```

*which gets a Set including either Integer or String values*

A `Set<T>` can have elements of only one type , the type of `T` , so either `Integer` or `String` , not both.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a list as of now you are returning a single list.

Change it to :

```
private List<Set<T>> createChunkSet(Set<T> set) {
    set = new HashSet<T>();
    List<Set<T>> list  = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();
    list.add(set);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to write a generic method which gets a Set including either Integer or String 
>   values. The Method should partition that given Set and return a list which contains sets of 
>   the generic type.

OK, parameter to this method should be a java.util.Set. Object is the common superclass for String and Integer.

But the return type?

You require the returned list should contain 2 Sets, Set and Set. This cannot be typesafely written in Java using generics (and not in any other language) - a typesafe list is a list of object all of the same type!

What you want to achive could be done as follows:

```
public <T> Set<T> createChunkSet(Set<Object> set, Class<T> filterClass)  {
    Set<T> chunkedSet = new HashSet<T>();
    for (Object o : set) {
        if (filterClass.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
            chunkedSet.add(filterClass.cast(o));
        }
    }
    return chunkedSet;
}
```

This method would have to be called like this:

```
Set<Integer> ints = createChunkSet(myUntypesSet, Integer.class);
```